# If we divide 'withdrawal' into prefix, root, and suffix; how will it be?

Tags: affixes

Like when we say un-happi-ness (prefix, root, and suffix), how can we divide withdrawal?

Answer (score 3):

*-al* is certainly a suffix, but whether you regard *with-* as a prefix, or *withdraw* as an unanalysable word is a matter of choice, depending partly on your timescale.

Historically, certainly *withdraw* derives from prefix *with-* and root *draw*. *With-* is also found in *withhold* and *withstand*, and meant "against". But it is not a productive prefix in modern English, and its meaning is not obvious in *withdraw*, so I suspect that most people's mental lexicon does not list *withdraw* as a prefixed word.

Answer (score -1):

According to Etymology Online Dictionary:
withdraw (v.)
early 13c. (transitive), "to take back," from with "away" + drawen "to draw.
So: With - prefix.
Draw - root.

withdrawal (n.)
1820s, "act of taking back," also "retraction of a statement," from withdraw + -al. 
So: -al - suffix.